# how to transfer a time which was zero at year of 0000(maybe) to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, gps

I have a gps time in the database,and when I do some query,I have to use the java.util.Date,however I found that I do not know how to change the gps time to java.util.Date.

Here is a example:

```
The readable time   === The GPS time
2010-11-15 13:10:00 === 634254192000000000 
2010-11-15 14:10:00 === 634254228000000000
```

The period of the two date is "36000000000",,obviously it stands for one hour,so I think the unit of the gps time in the db must be nanosecond.

```
1 hour =3600 seconds= 3600*1000 milliseconds ==  3600*1000*10000 nanoseconds
```

Then I try to convert the gps time:

Take the " 634254228000000000" as example,it stands for("2010-11-15 14:10:00");

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
Date d = new Date(63425422800000L);
System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
```

The result is

```
3979-11-15 13:00:00+0000.
```

Of course it is wrong,then I try to calculate :

```
63425422800000/3600000/24/365=2011.xxx
```

So it seems that the gps time here is not calcuated from Epoch(1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000).
It maybe something like (0001-01-01 00:00:00+0000).

Then I try to use the following method:

```
Date date_0=sdf.parse("0001-01-01 00:00:00+0000");
Date d = new Date(63425422800000L);
System.out.println(sdf.format(d.getTime() + date_0.getTime()));

The result is:
2010-11-13 13:00:00+0000. :(
```

Now I am confusing about how to calculate this gps time.

Any suggestion?

Comment: BTW there was no such thing as year 0. Before year 1 there was year -1 (1 BC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that GPS time is 15 seconds ahead from UTC :
[gps-time-representation-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038229/gps-time-representation-library)

> There are other time and date systems as well; for example, the time scale used by the satellite-based global positioning system (GPS) is synchronized to UTC but is not adjusted for leap seconds.

Quoted from : [Java Util Date API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 3):

1 millisecond = 1 000 000 nanoseconds

so...
1 hour =3600 seconds= 3600*1000 milliseconds ==  3600*1000*10000000 nanoseconds

Comment: Thanks,so can you tell me what is the unit of "36000000000",I know it stand for one hour.

Comment: It's nanoseconds. 1000 nanoseconds is 1 microsecond. 1000 microseconds is 1 millisecond. 1000 millseconds is 1 second. `Date` takes milliseconds. In other words, you need to get rid of six zeroes, not four.

Comment: In fact, I am not exactly sure the unit of "36000000000",I just know it means one hour. If I get rid of six zeros,then it will be "36000",what does it mean?

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking up some documentation for GPS time to see how it is calculated. I would just be conjecturing if I answered that, and it would probably be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

GPS time was zero at `6-Jan-1980` as opposed to Epoch which was zero at `1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000`

Here is the simple Java code I used to convert GPS time (ms) to Java Date:

```
BigInteger gpsTime = new BigInteger("973865400000");
GregorianCalendar calendar = 
                      new GregorianCalendar(1980, Calendar.JANUARY, 6, 0, 0, 0);
long gpsDiff = calendar.getTimeInMillis(); // gps offset to a   
Date javaDate = new Date(gpsDiff + gpsTime.longValue());
System.out.println("Java Date: " + javaDate);
// prints: Java Date: Mon Nov 15 14:10:00 EST 2010
```

Comment: I know this,and it seems that the time in my example is not calculated from 6-Jan-1980

Comment: @hguser: As per my calculation `2010-11-15 14:10:00` in GPS milli sec should be `973865400000` so not really sure about the value `634254228000000000` in your database.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Now I am sure that the "634254228000000000" in my db is neither zero at  "6-Jan-1980" nor "1970-01-01",and through "63425422800000/3600000/24/365=2011.xxx
",it seems that it is zero at some day like "0001-01-01 00:00:00",but I can not get the exactly instant.