# How to get GPS Time and TAI time in Java?

Tags: java, time, tai-time

Is there a way to get the current [GPS time](http://www.gpstime.com/) and [TAI time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time)?

( [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)'s return value is POSIX time, which isn't a linear representation of time. )

Comment: for gps time http://stackoverflow.com/q/3038229/776084

Answer (score 2):

Your option is to look at the ThreeTen project, which is the reference implementation of the 
JSR-310 (new Java Date and Time spec). You can find a `TAIInstant` class in the [javadocs](http://threeten.sourceforge.net/apidocs/)

It's claimed to be still in alpha, though