# GPS time in millis to UTC format

Tags: java, swing, date

Is there any direct way of converting a certain amount of seconds starting on January  6th 1980 to an UTC format like YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss?

EDIT: Here is the code working:

```
private Date gpsInit;
//...
try{
        String ds = "06/01/1980";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        gpsInit = df.parse(ds);
    }
    catch(ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to parse January 6th 1980");
    }

    textField = new JFormattedTextField(format);
    textField.setText(formatUTC(min));
//...
private String formatUTC(int timeValue) {
        long diference = timeValue + gpsInit.getTime()/1000;
        String pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        Date utcNow = new Date(diference*1000);
        return utcFormat.format(utcNow);
    }
```

Comment: Leap seconds might be problematic.

Comment: Similar Question: [GPS Time Representation library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3038229/642706).

Comment: What is "min" here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

1. Construct a `Date` object (via `Calendar`) for the `06.01.1980 00:00:00` date
2. call `getTime()` to get the milliseconds since EPOCH
3. Add your milliseconds to that
4. Construct a new `Date` object with that milliseconds value.
5. Format it however you want (`SimpleDateFormatter` for example)

Comment: But... if i get seconds from 6th January 1980, and then I add the seconds since 1st January 1070, I would be in 2050 more or less. No?

Comment: @RomanRdgz, eh - not sure I understand your question. EPOCH is 01.01.1970, if you get the milliseconds from 06.01.1980 to EPOCH and add your *milliseconds since 06.01.1980*, you'll be able to construct a `Date` object with *milliseconds from 01.01.1970*.

Comment: @RomanRdgz, I see you changed your question - well it doesn't change things too much, divide and multiply by 1000 in the appropriate places.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. You must excuse me, I'm still sleepy. I'll have a try