# How to convert UTC time into local time in Java?

Tags: java, time

I have time coming from gpslocation service in 1352437114052 format. Can some one tell me how to convert this into local time either in Java or Matlab or Excel.

Comment: Find out that the offset between local time and UTC is, in milliseconds, and add/subtract it from the value you have here. That gives local time in milliseconds since the beginning of 1970 in your timezone.

Comment: Similar Question, [GPS Time Representation library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3038229/642706) and [GPS time in millis to UTC format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9599176/642706).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new `Date` from your milliseconds since epoch. Then use a `DateFormat` to format it in your desired timezone.

```
Date date = new Date(1352437114052L);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: The result is string. But, how to return Long or TimeStamp?

Answer (score 4):

This is an [*epoch time*](http://www.epochconverter.com) and it represents Fri, 09 Nov 2012 04:58:34 GMT. This numeric value is an absolute point in time, irrespective to time zone.

If you want to see that point in time in different time zone, use [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html):

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
c.setTimeInMillis(1352437114052L);
c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //20:58 the day before
```

Comment: The key is the use of `TimeZone`. Otherwise you get the default zone.

Comment: Use `DateTime converted = c.getTime();` to get converted DateTime

Answer (score 1):

The modern Java answer using the JVM’s time zone setting (typically the same as your computer’s time zone):

```
long time = 1_352_437_114_052L;
ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Running on my computer I get

> 2012-11-09T05:58:34.052+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

To specify a time zone:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Almaty"));
```

> 2012-11-09T10:58:34.052+06:00[Asia/Almaty]

### Question: Will that work on Android too?

To answer [tinker’s comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315734/how-to-convert-utc-time-into-local-time-in-java/50836151#comment88734744_50828744): Yes. I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, and it works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

@Steve Kuo answered the question directly, almost. Here's a more general solution for **machine's local time**, including **daylight saving time**, where `a` is of type `BasicFileAttributes` as reported from Windows directory entry in `public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path f, BasicFileAttributes a)` during `Files.walkFileTree`:

```
  String modifyDate;
  Date date = new Date(a.lastModifiedTime().to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
  format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
  modifyDate = (format.format(date)).substring(0,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(timeStamp+"");

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a z");
String dateString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(dateString);
```

---

Output :

```
timestamp : 1528860439258

dateformat from sdf : 2018-06-12 08:27:19 PM PDT
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Instant.ofEpochMilli will not work on Android API level < 26. So, you need to tone it down. The question here is on Java, not specifically Android but there is a way to say it.

Comment: @tinker Thanks for mentioning it. Indeed `Instant.ofEpochMilli` can work nicely on Android below API level 26. See [my edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836151/5772882).

Answer (score 0):

Since new Date(String string) is deprecated now(which is the accepted answer), we can use `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` to get the system time zone

```
  public String getZonedDate(String dateStr) {
    DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(dateStr).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    return  utcDateTime
        .toDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
  }
```