# How to get time send by GPS

Tags: java-me, gps

Hi I'm developing J2ME application and I'm interested that
is it possible to get GPS time (time is sent by GPS sattelites)?
how to get it?

Comment: Are you using an API to call the GPS time?

Comment: I'm using javax.microedition.location library

Comment: Have you seen this q&a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038229/gps-time-representation-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Location](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~czhou/docs/jsr179/lapi/) class has method `getTimestamp()` but I'm not sure if it returns satellite fix time.

The [Location](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~czhou/docs/jsr179/lapi/) class has method `getExtraInfo(String)`. If you call it with `application/X-jsr179-location-nmea` you will get [NMEA](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) string of current fix. There is definitely info about satellite fix time.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not return the coordinates using `javax.microedition.location.Coordinates`

You could then work out the current time in that timezone given the current coordinates?